# Python slicing and replacing

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand python slicing better, and how it works in the context of mutating arrays. Is this in-place? Is it O(1) memory or less? What's happening throughout this line?

For an example, if nums is an array and f is an integer. Where `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and `f = 3`.

```
nums[:] = nums[-f:] + nums[:-f]
```

Does `nums[:]` use memory? I know that `nums[-f:] + nums[:-f]` reassigns the value based on f but what does the addition do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This splits the list into two halves based on `f`. `[-f:]` extracts the last `f` elements of the list as a new list and `[:-f]` extracts the beginning of the list to `len(nums) - f` as a new list.

`nums[:]` uses memory for temporarily storing removed objects (`recycle_on_stack`/`recycle`) and copying the new ones into the list. `[:]` means we traverse the entire structure which means `norig` is the full length of the list and we have to incur

```
s = norig * sizeof(PyObject *);
memcpy(recycle, &item[ilow], s);
```

on the whole list. See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c87a667bb367ace1de6bd1577fdb4f66947da52/Objects/listobject.c#L628).

The slice assignment mutates `nums` [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), sort of like a splice operation.

`+` in this context is [list concatenation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c87a667bb367ace1de6bd1577fdb4f66947da52/Objects/listobject.c#L518). The operation creates and returns a new list.

I'm counting at least 4 whole copies being made of `nums` in the above example (the two slices add up to one, one for the concatenation, and another two for the slice assignment).

Comment: sorry, do you mind explaining more on `nums[-f:]` and `nums[:-f]` in the case where `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and `f = 3` bc when I `print(nums[-f:])` it returns `[2, 3, 4]` and when I print `print(nums[:-f])` it returns `[5, 6, 7, 1]`. Why?

Comment: I'm seeing `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 6, 7]` for your example.

Comment: oooh, sorry stupid mistake! print statement is in the wrong location.

Comment: A note for future learners: nums[:] is needed if the parameters wanted are slicing an array in-place