# Confused about python lists and functions

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python having previously used JavaScript, C++, LISP etc. I'm rather confused about something. Here is a simplified working example:

```
def function1(list1):
    list1.append(7)
    list1 = list1[3:]

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
function1(list1)
print(list1)
```

When I pass list1 through function1 and then print list1 it returns [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. I expect it to return [4,5,6,7]. The function seems to be actioning list1.append(7) but not actioning list1 = list1[3:]. Why? Lists are mutable and the function has no issue appending an element to a list, so why will it not remove elements? How do I achieve what I am trying to achieve without introducing new variables (which I'd rather not do)?

Comment: Read about variable scope... but also what a variable *is* in python.

Comment: It appends the element to the list because the list is mutable, yes. But you are only assigning the smaller slice to _a variable_, you're not mutating the list object with that slice.

Comment: I think I understand what the scope of a variable is. I'm confused as to why list1 acts like a global variables when I append to it but as a local variable when I remove the first 3 members

Comment: FWIW, it would work exactly the same in Javascript…

Comment: @deceze ok, is it possible to mutate the list with a slice?

Comment: Add `print(id(list1))` at every line to see what's going on...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58152087/476.

Comment: None of the other linked questions which have been deemed an answer to my question (but which have answered completely different questions) have been of any use to me. I've figured out that writing list1[:] = list1[3:] solves it. Could have just told me :) thanks anyway

Comment: @Oliver Variables and the objects they point to are not the same thing. `list1.append(7)` means "give me whatever object the variable `list1` is pointing at, and call that object's `append` method", whereas `list1 = list1[3:]` means "rebind the variable `list1` to point at this new object". You aren't changing the underlying object, you're just changing what object the variable points at.

Comment: The locally-scoped variable `list1` within the scope of the function, and the variable `list1` in the global scope are two distinct variables that both happen to point at the same underlying object (initially.) Rebinding the local `list1` has no effect on the global `list1`.

Comment: @PaulM. So, if you add a third line list1.append(8), will it affect the parameter or the local ?

Comment: @PaulM. Thank you very much Paul for the clear explanation - I understand now!

Comment: @kingsjester I just tested it:  it would affect the local variable.

Comment: `list1 = list1[3:]` creates a new list object with the expression `list1[3:]` and assigns that to the local variable `list1`. On the other hand, `list1.append(7)` mutates the list object being referenced by `list1`.

Comment: Python does support slice notation to mutate a list, `list1[:] = list[3:]`, although this also creates a new list object with the expression `list1[3:]`, the `list[:] = whatever` *mutates* the object being referenced by `list1`, this is *slice assignment*. Simple assignment never mutates. It simply rebinds the *name* to another object.

Comment: See: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html it is really the best explanation of the semantics of Python